# What happens to the "Red Comet"?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I've just finished **A Dance With Dragons** and realized that the *[Red Comet](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_comet)* which appeared in the early books had made no appearances lately.

I've been reading the series before going to sleep so I wasn't always at my most alert and may have missed it but I don't remember anyone commenting about the comet disappearing.
Since it seemed to be such a big deal for many people I would expect the plot to reflect when it stopped appearing (or if it didn't stop why is nobody noting it as they did in the past?).

Did I miss something?

Comment: In the [last chapter of ACOK](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_69) Bran sees something that might be the comet disappearing through Summer's eyes: `The smoke and ash clouded his eyes, and in the sky he saw a great winged snake whose roar was a river of flame. He bared his teeth, but then the snake was gone.` Don't know if its the last sighting of the comet (or even if that really is the comet).

Comment: @TLP - Good enough to be an answer

Comment: When Comet Hale-Bopp came by in 1997, how many people did you mention its absence to after it had gone? I'm betting the answer is zero, and why should you expect Westeros to be any different?

Comment: @MikeScott, in 1997 I don't remember people commenting on the comet being a herald of the end days and discussing what it signifies.

Comment: @SystemDown No, I cannot say if that is the last time it is mentioned, and it is debatable whether it is about the comet, and if so, about the disappearance of the comet. Worth a comment, though, perhaps can be combined with other observations.

Comment: @Motti: These guys saw Hale-Bopp as a sign: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven's_Gate_(religious_group)

Comment: @yatima2975 sure but they were nutters weren't they? Anyway I don't remember seeing Hale-Bopp with naked eyes. Granted you see less of the stars in urban settings than you would in a medieval settings but from the description in the books it would seem that the red comet was much brighter than any comet in my lifetime.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the comet is still there. From a storytelling point of view, if nothing has really changed regarding it, there's zero value in having characters go "Yep, the comet is still there."

Comment: @AnthonyGrist true but that didn't stop GRRM from having characters repeatedly refer to it in the first two books.

Comment: Maybe it’s turned into a meteor, and will be what finally finishes the story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comet seems to have disappeared from the sky, as of *A Dance with Dragons* at least. Beyond not being mentioned anymore by the characters, Salladhor Saan, when talking to Davos Seaworth about leaving the cause of Stannis Baratheon and receiving payment for his damaged ships, mentions it:

> When Davos had tried to assure him that he would have his payment, Salla had erupted.
>
> "When, when? On the morrow, on the new moon, when  the red comet comes again? He is promising me gold and gems, always promising, but this gold I have not seen.

Salladhor's choice of words seems to indicate that the comet is no longer visible in the Westerosi sky, as its "coming again" is used as an example of something which one doesn't know when will happen.

Comment: @Thanks for this, I don't remember these lines, are they from a book or from the TV series?

Comment: It's a line from _A Dance with Dragons_, chapter 9.

Answer (score 7):

Since no answer has come after 24 hours, I will add my comment as an answer. Though with some reservations as to its accuracy.

In the [last chapter of *A Clash of Kings*](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_69) Bran sees something that might be the comet disappearing through Summer's eyes:

> *The smoke and ash clouded his eyes, and in the sky he saw a great winged snake whose roar was a river of flame. He bared his teeth, but then the snake was gone.*

I don't know if its the *last* sighting of the comet, or even if it really is the comet -- Summer's point of view is not exactly straightforward. If it is actually the comet disappearing, it sounds like the comet fell out of the sky at this exact point in time, not just gradually disappeared.

This passage is from the last chapter of ACOK, as I said, so any mention in ASOS beyond this point would imply that this observation is not correct. Although of course with GRRM, one can never completely trust in a linear timeline between chapters.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very interesting. However it doesn't answer my main question (perhaps I wasn't clear enough). I was surprised that the comet changed from being very _present_ in the story and commented on, to suddenly not being mentioned at all. I would expect at least a mention in passing something like _Well it seems that the red comment wasn't an omen to the return of house of Targaryen after all_

Comment: The red comment? :) Well, from what I could gather in your question, you asked if you had missed the comet being mentioned, or disappearing. Was that not your question? As near as I could tell, no one actually said the comet heralded a Targaryen comeback. More like, everyone saw it as a herald of their own fortune. Only Old Nan said something to that effect: `it be dragons, boy`. Some mention "blood and fire", which is the Targaryen words, but not Targs directly.

Comment: Heh Oooooops ;)